# Importing a CSV file in pandas into a pandas dataframe with parse error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, parsing

I am trying to import a .csv file `wpas_js_ticket_tickets.csv` to a  pandas data frame but it is not working
my code:

```
import pandas as pd
```

```
incidencias04 = pd.read_csv('wpas_js_ticket_tickets.csv')
```

and Jupyter gives back:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-12-cc00fa52a784> in <module>
----> 1 incidencias04 = pd.read_csv('wpas_js_ticket_tickets.csv')

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    674         )
    675 
--> 676         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    677 
    678     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
_read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    452 
    453     try:
--> 454         data = parser.read(nrows)
    455     finally:
    456         parser.close()

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)    1131     def read(self, nrows=None):    1132         nrows =
_validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
-> 1133         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)    1134     1135         # May alter columns / col_dict

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)    2035     def read(self, nrows=None):    2036         try:
-> 2037             data = self._reader.read(nrows)    2038         except StopIteration:    2039             if self._first_chunk:

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 6
```

Apparently, the problem is the .csv file cause I'm trying to do it with another file and its working good.
Could you please help me understand what's wrong?

Comment: provide first few lines of the csv

Comment: incidencias04.head(5)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-103f4c46daff> in <module>
----> 1 incidencias04.head(5)

NameError: name 'incidencias04' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

I was exporting from PHPmyAdmin the CSV as a cvs for Excel. Exported another copy as a "plain csv" and worked it out.

Thanks!